# Dynamic UI & Accessing Data (Shiny)

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I've a problem with my shiny code which is somewhat related with the two questions I linked below.

So i've made a dynamic UI :

```
output$hmgroupsmean <-renderUI({
numGroups <- as.integer(input$HMgroups)

lapply(1:numGroups, function(i) {

  numericInput(paste0("group_", i),
               label= paste("Mean", i),
               min=0, 
               max=1000,
               value= 10)
})
})
```

that display N numericInput depending on how many groups the user has chosen. 
Then I just want to retrieve all the mean and there begin the problem :
I tried what is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705343/accessing-inputs-created-in-renderui-in-shiny) but it doesnt work :

```
   output$PowerAnalysisANOVA <- renderPlot({

   allmean = c()

   lapply(1:numGroups, function(i){
     allmean[i] <- input[[paste0("group_", i)]]
   }) 

qplot(allname)

})
```

it returns : 
**Error : argument "env" is missing, with no default**

then i tried something a tad more exotic :

```
 output$PowerAnalysisANOVA <- renderPlot({

   allname = c()
   allmean = c()
   lapply(1:numGroups, function(i){
     allname[i] <- paste0("input$group_" ,i)
     allmean[i] <- get(allname[i])
   }) 

qplot(allmean)
})
```

But it doesn't work : **Error :object 'input$group_1' not found**

Edit after AndriyTkach's comment :

```
output$PowerAnalysisANOVA <- renderPlot({

   allname = c()
   allmean = c()
   lapply(1:numGroups, function(i){
     allname[i] <- eval(parse (text = paste0("input$group_" ,i))) 
     allmean[i] <- get(allname[i])
   }) 

qplot(allmean)
})
```

It returns a new **Error : invalid first argument**

AndriyTkach proposed that :

```
for (i in 1:numGroups) 
eval (parse (text = paste0("allmean[", i, "] <- input$group_" ,i)))
```

Which work a lot better : no Error message but it only work for 2 and 3 groups , the fourth and up is not taken into account
[Create dynamic number of input elements with R/Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19130455/create-dynamic-number-of-input-elements-with-r-shiny)
[accessing inputs created in renderUI in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23705343/accessing-inputs-created-in-renderui-in-shiny)

Comment: try `eval (parse (text = paste0("input$group_" ,i)))`

Comment: Thanks , but it doesn't work : I have a new error : invalid first argument

Comment: substitute `lapply(1:numGroups, function(i){
     allname[i] <- paste0("input$group_" ,i)
     allmean[i] <- get(allname[i])
   })` with `lapply(1:numGroups, function(i){
     eval(parse(text = paste0("allmean[", i, "] <- input$group_", i)))
   })` ?

Comment: I don't really understand what you did but It returns : argument "env" is missing, with no default

Comment: you don't need to use `get`. see previous comment

Comment: Oh ok so that : 
       lapply(1:numGroups, function(i){ 
         allmean[i] = eval (parse (text = paste0("input$group_" ,i))) 
       })

but it also returns :  argument "env" is missing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78097/discussion-between-boo-and-andriytkach).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some discussion with AndriyTkach : I have a working program :

```
output$PowerAnalysisANOVA <- renderPlot({
allmean = c()

for (i in 1:values$numGroups) 
eval (parse (text = paste0("allmean[", i, "] <- input$group_" ,i))) 

qplot(allmean)
})
```

And I had forgotten to make a reactive variable :

```
values <- reactiveValues()

output$hmgroupsmean <-renderUI({
values$numGroups <- as.integer(input$HMgroups)
apply(1:values$numGroups, function(i) {

  numericInput(paste0("group_", i),
               label= paste("Condition", i),
               min=0, 
               max=1000,
               value= 10)
})
})
```